# Update VM after recipe update with 'vagrant reload'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtualbox, chef-infra, vagrant

I have created VM with ***vagrant up***. Then I have changed an recipe and run ***vagrant reload*** to update my VM according to new recipe and it doesn't change my files according to new recipe. So I need to ***vagrant destroy*** and ***vagrant up*** to update my VM with new recipe.

**Is it ok?**

Here I tried to update my config:

```
template "/etc/nginx/sites-available/vagrant.conf" do
  owner 'vagrant'
  mode 0644
  source 'host.conf.erb'
  notifies :reload, 'service[nginx]'
end
```

And it updates only by **vagrant destroy** + **vagrant up**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official documentation(http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/provisioners.html) says you have 3 different options to have provisioning applied on a VM:

- `vagrant provision`
- `vagrant reload`
- `vagrant up`

If you just want to get provisioning reapplied, it's recommended to use `vagrant provision` over the other options because this command only trigger the provisioning process (while `vagrant reload` and `vagrant up` do a bunch of things more).

Finally, if you are having the need to `destroy` and `up` just to get your VM updated, maybe the issue is with your recipe. Try to share the snippet ([pastbin](http://pastebin.com/), [gist](https://gist.github.com/) etc.) pointing which part of the code is not working, so the community could help you better, ok?

Comment: It seems that ***vagrant provision*** is what I need.